# Struts 2 json validation return error Json when validation correct

Tags: validation, struts2

action mapping

```
<action name="test" class="com.val.Test" >
        <result type="stream">
            <param name="contentType">text/html</param>
            <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
        </result>
        <interceptor-ref name="jsonValidationWorkflowStack">
        </interceptor-ref>  
    </action>
```

Test-Validation.xml

```
<validators>
<field name="name">
    <field-validator type="required" >
        <message>You must select a name</message>
    </field-validator>
</field>
</validators>
```

when I request `/test?name=21&struts.enableJSONValidation=true`

got the response

```
{ "fieldErrors": {"name":["You must select a name"]}}
```

Comment: Do you have getter/setter for `name` variable?

Comment: Thank you Aleksandr M. It is working when I place fields in action and write getters and setters. but it is not working when action is model driven.

Answer (score 0):

You must use **RequiredString Validator** instead of **Required Validator**.

RequiredString is for *text* fields only, Required is for *all* the other fields

```
<validators>
<field name="name">
    <field-validator type="requiredstring" >
        <message>You must select a name</message>
    </field-validator>
</field>
</validators>
```

[Link to the official documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/requiredstring-validator.html)

> RequiredStringValidator checks that a String field is non-null and has
>   a length > 0. (i.e. it isn't ""). The "trim" parameter determines
>   whether it will {@link String#trim() trim} the String before
>   performing the length check. If unspecified, the String will be
>   trimmed.

Comment: that's not working test?name=21&struts.enableJSONValidation=true

Comment: What do you mean with "not working" ? Do you have any exception ? Could you post the Action code (by editing your answer) ?

Comment: I'm getting this { "fieldErrors": {"name":["You must select a name"]}}
even if I send name=someText

Comment: it returns that with `required` and with `requiredstring` too ??